# Get actual spelling of lib clang cursor/type

Tags: python, c++, clang, libclang

I writing a script to detect formatting errors in my C++ code. (for example making sure all member variables are prefixed with `m_`). One of things I want to do is make sure types that are pointers have the asterix attached to the type (`int* num`, not `int *num`).

So I need to get the text of the type as it is in the source code. However getting the spelling of the cursor or type returns a pretty printed version, it will always return `int *`, even if the source has `int*`.

To get around this I get the extent of the cursor and get the substring from the source file and check that. However there seems to be no way to get the extent of a type, and so I can't get the actual spelling of it? Is there some way to do this? perhaps by getting the tokens of the of the type and then getting the extent of those?

(I'm using the python bindings but could switch to the C API if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Get the spelling:

```
std::string symbol = clang_getCString(clang_getCursorSpelling(Cursor));
```

Look for a pointer declarator:

```
case CXType_Pointer:
{
  // ...
}
```

Use `clang_tokenize`, then use that to look for the placement of the `*`.

```
// Tokens retrieved with clang_tokenize
// symbol declared earlier
auto finder = std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), symbol);
if (*(finder) == "*")
{
  if (*(finder + 1)) == " ") { /* ... */ } // int* asdf
} else if (*(finder) == " ") {
  if (*(finder + 1)) == "*") { /* ... */ } // int *asdf 
}
```

Of course this is pseudo-code. Code not touched by compiler's hands.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tokens don't include white space though.

Answer (score 0):

Libclang is a great tool to find member variables that match (or don't match a pattern), but there's a much easier way to solve the problem of pretty printing pointers and references in your codebase and that's to use [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) which is *a tool to format C/C++/Java/JavaScript/Objective-C/Protobuf code*.

Clang-format has a huge number of [options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), but the one that's probably most of interest is `PointerAlignment`, which can have one of the values: Left, Right or Middle, which reformats pointers (and references) appropriately.

You can generate a new config file for clang-format from one of the online tools or from a built-in style:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

Editing that file to set `PointerAlignment` to Left and running:

```
clang-format main.cpp
```

On a "poorly" formatted piece of code like:

```
// main.cpp
int main()
{
    int a;
    int* b;
    int *c;
    int& d;
    int &d;
    int * e;
    const int * f;
    const int * const g;
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
// main.cpp
int main() {
  int a;
  int* b;
  int* c;
  int& d;
  int& d;
  int* e;
  const int* f;
  const int* const g;
  return 0;
}
```

With similar results for the other settings.

If you really do need to do this from code you can use [libformat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibFormat.html), the library that underpins clang-format, or you can use invoke clang-format [from a subprocess](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/tools/clang-format/clang-format.py), which is how other tools in the clang codebase do this.

Comment: I looked into clang format, but it seemed there was no way to define custom rules. I didn't look at libformat, but at an initial glance, it seems it can only call the format process, and not define custom rules.

Comment: Consider doing this in two stages - in the first stage you can use libclang or [clang replacements](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_clang/matchers_replacements.cpp) to find (and possibly replace the member variables), and then correct the pointers/references in a second pass.